# python dict object has not attribute read

Tags: python, html

I want to get image file from web,and then send to API_Search_Handler which i can not change the code of. Remove the UploadImageHandler i can do that,but I want to use the middle handler to receive call back from API_handler which is image and then show in the web.Can i do that without UploadImageHandler?
Or how should I fix the error and send correct data type to API_handler? Limit of the code of API_handler is fixed..

index.html

```
<form action="/uploadimage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <p><input type='file' multiple="true" name="file" id="file"/></p>
            <p><span>:</span><input type="int" size="3" value="120" name="dist"/>
            &nbsp<span>:</span><input type="int" size="3" value="50" name="max_num" id="max_num" /></p>
            <p><span>：</span></p>
            <p>all:<input type="checkbox" name="dir" value="all" checked></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="" id="submit" /></p>
        </form><br/><br/>


 class UploadImageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            dist=self.get_body_argument("dist")
            print self.request.body
            max_num=self.get_body_argument("max_num")
            imagedir=self.get_body_argument("dir")

            for f in self.request.files['file']:
                print f['filename']
                url = 'http://192.168.1.234:8968'
                files = {'file':{"filename":f["filename"],"body":f["body"]}}
                data={'dir':imagedir,'dist':dist,'max_num':max_num}
                requests.post( url + r'/api/search' ,data=data,files = files)
            self.write("save ok")
```

error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1346, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/home/zhengminpeng/python-test/web/handlers/index.py", line 24, in post
    requests.post( url + r'/api/search' ,data=data,files = files)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 450, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 381, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 307, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 452, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 150, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

API_Search_Handler

```
class API_Search_Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        print 'async search'
        dist = self.get_argument('dist')
        if dist is None:
            dist = 81.0
        num = self.get_argument('max_num')
        if num is None:
            num = 6
        subDir = self.get_argument('dir')
        if subDir == '':
            subDir = 'any'
        logger.info('dist=%s, num=%s' %(dist, num))

        for f in self.request.files['file']:
            print f['filename']
            logFile = open(config.LOG_DIR_PATH + 'log_' + str(time.clock())+'_'+f['filename'], 'w')
            logFile.write(f['body'])
            logFile.close()

            featureUrl = 'http://' + config.FEATURE_SVR_ADDR+ ':'  + str(config.FEATURE_SVR_PORT)
            featureUrl = featureUrl + featuresvr_urls.SEARCH_FEATURE_HANDLE_URL
            featureUrl = featureUrl + ('?filename=%s&dist=%d&max_num=%d&dir=%s' % (f['filename'], int(dist), int(num), subDir))

            def on_response(response):
                self.write(response.body)
                self.finish()
            req = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(featureUrl,method='POST', body=f['body'])

            http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
            http.fetch(req, callback=on_response)
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because requests doesn't expect a dictionary for the items in the `files` dict.

According to [the documentation](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), using a simple tuple should work:

```
files = {'file': (f["filename"], f["body"])}
```